# iOS web browser Google search

Tags: ios, objective-c

The assignment was to take anything with a space in the search query, assume it is a search criteria, and run it through a Google programmatically. Here is the code:

```
NSString *URLString = textField.text;

if ([URLString rangeOfString:@" "].location > 0) {

     NSString *searchString = [URLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

     NSURL *searchURL =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com/search?q=%@",searchString]];

     NSURLRequest *searchRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:searchURL];

    [self.webview loadRequest:searchRequest];
}
```

I'm sure it's sloppy, but I was just curious as to why it's not functional. I took it through the debugger, and everything up to "searchString" seems to go well. I'm at a loss.

Let me know if I need to add more code.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a clear question here and it's not obvious what a useful answer would contain. "it's not functional" suggests this code sample does not work as intended but that tells us very little: What input text did you provide? What did you expect to happen and how would you know if it was working? What unexpected result did you see, what were you able to learn about what actually happened?

Comment: I created a test project with your snippet in it and searches with spaces are loading in the webview for me. You didn't specify if you created your web view from code or if you used a storyboard. If you used a storyboard I would suggest checking that your web view outlets are connected so that when you call self.webview you aren't calling a nil object. Also check that your search field outlet is connected to your property. If you're creating the web view in code don't forget to add it to the view controllers view and set the frame to something visible.

Comment: Sorry about that....

Comment: @Jonah

I made several different entries, but they all had a space. On the browser that I've created (for a project), an entry that does has a space is assumed to be Google search.

What it is _supposed_ to do is take the entered text, turn the spaces into "+", and run it through a Google query. The browser should have loaded the search as it loads any other web site. It, literally, did nothing.

Comment: @digitalHound

The entire browser is made programmatically. The rest of the program works (this is just the Google search piece). By that I mean web pages (typed in the appropriate format) load, and you are able to view them.

For some reason, this isn't yielding any results for me.

Comment: @BrandonWade "did nothing" is unfortunately not very useful. I can't see your project from here so guessing why "nothing" happened is likely to be error-prone. There are however useful next steps you can take to learn more about what is happening. You seem to be stepping through this with a debugger already; what request are you creating and what url does it use, do those seem reasonable, does that url load as you would expect in curl or a browser? Is your webview non-nil, is it even in the window?

Answer (score 2):

I created a project using Xcode 6.3, storyboards, and ran in the iPhone 6 simulator and it works just fine. Here are two screenshots from the simulator:

[image: Without spaces]

[image: With Spaces]

And here's the code I used. It's slightly different from yours and I also included my whole VC:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)googleItButtonPress:(id)sender {

    NSString *searchString = self.searchText.text;

    if ([searchString rangeOfString:@" "].location > 0) {

        NSString *searchStringModified = [searchString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

        NSURL *searchURL =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com/search?q=%@",searchStringModified]];

        NSURLRequest *searchRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:searchURL];

        [self.webView loadRequest:searchRequest];
    }
}

@end
```

I'm also getting this when I print the value of my modified search string if I set a breakpoint for the debugger:

```
(lldb) po searchStringModified
google+stuff
```

Looks like you're good to go. In this case just use storyboards and make sure your UIWebView is connected to your VC code.

Comment: And of course the "Google it" button is hooked up to that IBAction

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what happened, but I suffered a case of spontaneous resolution. Thanks, everyone, for your time and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thing this work fine for me

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *URLString = @"HEllo World";

    if ([URLString rangeOfString:@" "].location > 0) {

        NSString *searchString = [URLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

        NSURL *searchURL =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com/search?q=%@",searchString]];

        NSURLRequest *searchRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:searchURL];

        [webview loadRequest:searchRequest];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Started Loading");
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

}
```

[image]